# Webpack development is recompiling after change, but change not picked up on development site

Tags: webpack

I am currently getting to grips with webpack to try and help build my site. I have my webpack config files set up for both development and production and both seem to be working.

I wanted to have the development config setup to use hot module replacement so that it recompiles every time I make a change. This seems to be working and if I refresh the main.bundle.js in browser (`https://localhost:8081/main.bundle.js`) I can see the new changes, however when I refresh my website which loads the main.bundle.js file, it does not refresh with the changes.

I assume there must be something caching? Or something else I need to do so that the changes to main.bundle.js show on my website?

I am using the following command to run `NODE_ENV=development webpack && NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --progress --colors` and my webpack config for development is below...

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const ImageminPlugin = require('imagemin-webpack-plugin').default;

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client.js'),
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/styles/main/main.less')
  ],
  mode: 'development',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/public/'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    publicPath: 'https://localhost:8081/'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              babelrc: false,
              plugins: [
                [
                  '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
                  {
                    useBuiltIns: true
                  }
                ],
                '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
                '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
                '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime'
              ],
              presets: [
                [
                  '@babel/preset-env',
                  {
                    useBuiltIns: "usage"
                  }
                ],
                '@babel/preset-react'
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'css-loader'
            },
            {
              loader: 'less-loader'
            }
          ]
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[name].[ext]',
            outputPath: 'fonts/'
          }
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
  cache: false,
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendors: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendor',
          chunks: 'all'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: '[name].css' }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'src/assets/images', to: 'images'}]),
    new ImageminPlugin({ test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i })
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: '/dist/public/',
    publicPath: 'https://localhost:8081/',
    port: 8081,
    hot: true,
    disableHostCheck: true,
    headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
    https: {
      key: fs.readFileSync(
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'server.key'),
        'utf8'
      ),
      cert: fs.readFileSync(
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'server.cert'),
        'utf8'
      )
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you add a small repo with your setup?

Comment: In order for the HMR to work there is for a few things, like decide what should happend when there is a new update.